# Set permissions on NTFS folder to control permissions on contents of newly created subfolders

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs

I have the following example folder structure:

```
 U:\One\Two\A
 U:\One\Two\B
 U:\One\Two\C
 U:\One\Two\D
 U:\One\Two\E
```

Folder "One" and "Two" are set for regular users to only read, not modify them or their contents.
Folders "A" - "E" have read rights to themselves, and write rights to their contents/subfolders.

Does Windows allow one to set permissions on folder "Two" so that future created subfolders "F", "G", and so on, will get the same permissions as "A" - "E" do now? If not, what other solutions to achieve this result are there?

Comment: No; F and G would inherit the permissions of One and Two...."If not, what other solutions to achieve this result are there" change their inheritance when they are created or chnage your folder layout so they inherit the permissions you want then to inherit

Comment: What permissions exactly do you need applied to the subfolders A-E and so on?

Comment: [twisty](https://superuser.com/users/213131) - Folders "A" - "E" have read rights to themselves, and write rights to their contents/subfolders. I want the same for the newly created cousins.

Comment: (Please use @Twisty so I get notified). I saw this in your original question, but I want to know the exact NTFS permissions you have on these folders. For example, do the A-E folders have `Users:Read + Users:Modify(Subfolders and files only)`?

Comment: @[twisty](https://superuser.com/users/213131) Firstly, I hope the addition of @ notifies you, as use `[]()` to address people so if one changes their handle, it doesn't (annoyingly) make people reading the comments wonder who the commentor is addressing. Ideally SE would script a change of every @JohnDoe to the new handle when a change is made. As for the clarification, with the swap of the word "write" to "modify" (which in terms of basic permissions are the same principle) I believe we are on the same page.

Comment: Nope, I didn't get notified because you hyperlinked to my user. Just @Twisty is the only format that works. In any case, I've posted the solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Deny Changes to Immediate Subfolders/files but Allow Modify Rights to the Content of Subfolders

You only need to apply special permissions to the "Parent" folder of your A through E subfolders. In your case, the Parent folder is the `Two` folder.

#### Apply These Permissions To The Parent Folder:

- Users: `Read & execute (This folder, subfolders and files)`
- Users: `Modify (Subfolders and files only)`
- Users: `DENY 'Delete' (Subfolders only)` and enable `Apply these permissions to objects and/or containers within this container only`

  **Note:** Replace the `Users` group with the specific identity to which you wish to grant access.

  **Note:** You'll also need to grant Administrators (or a user assigned responsibility for adding/deleting subfolders) Full Control permissions to this folder. Otherwise no one will have permission to create subfolders.

#### Resulting Permissions for the 'Users' group:

- Cannot create, rename or delete folders or files immediately inside the parent folder
- Can create, rename, modify, and delete folders or files inside the *subfolders* of the parent folder.

#### Resulting Permissions in your case:

```
U:\One\Two   <-- "Parent" folder
 - Users can read everything below this folder
 - Users cannot create, rename, or delete files or folders here

U:\One\Two\A (through E)   <--- "Subfolder" of Parent
 - Users can create, rename, modify, and delete files or subfolders here
```

---

Obviously since the permissions assigned to the Parent folder are inherited, future folders created in the `Two` folder will automatically receive the same set of permissions.

Comment: So, it seems that by following the above permissions list everything works apart from the inability to Rename (and also initially name) a new subfolder in the `Two` folder. I can't wrap my head around how this is possible. Does Windows do some kind of delete and re-creation of folders upon a rename operation being performed?

Comment: Yes, renaming a folder/file requires the `Delete` permission. With this setup, only the administrator can/should rename the subfolders. If you grant your users the ability to rename, then they'll also be able to delete the subfolders in one fell swoop.

Comment: Okay, so how does one prevent the creation of new folders, as as it stands the identity that I gave the new permissions to can create new folders, and then they will probably wonder why they can't name it as they wish and just leave New Folder (x) after New Folder (x) folders in the parent directory. I added a DENY for Create folders / append data alongside the DENY entry for Delete, but this didn't prevent the creation of the New Folder folder.

Comment: Note to others, if testing with only one account, granting the `Change Permissions` right to it will allow folders to be created in `Two`, but it won't allow one to re/name them. Removing that permission will result in the exact abilities [twisty](https://superuser.com/users/213131) details above.

Answer (score 0):

No as stated F and G would inherit the permissions of One and Two
ICACLS can do what you want as a script - I have attached a CMD file that I used a while ago to do this every time I created a directory for a purpose -
I've modified it to use local groups rather than domain groups and some other stuff but it does work - but I hope this below helps explain how to use it

```
SET DIR=TESTPERMS 
SET DOMAIN=%COMPUTERNAME%\ 
SET DOMAIN= 
SET
ROOTPATH=%TEMP%\
REM SET ROOTPATH=U:\One\Two\ REM SET DIR=A

REM Create the groups locally on the machine - I added for debug
NET LOCALGROUP FSP_%DIR%_MODIFY /ADD 
NET LOCALGROUP FSP_%DIR%_READ /ADD 
NET LOCALGROUP FSP_%DIR%_READexecute /ADD 
NET LOCALGROUP FSP_%DIR%_FULLCONTROL /ADD 
NET LOCALGROUP FSP_%DIR%_WRITE /ADD

REM Make the directory I'm about to modify  
md %ROOTPATH%%DIR% 
REM   Make sure I know who the owner is - so I can take  ownership
ICACLS %ROOTPATH%%DIR% /setowner %DOMAIN%FSP_%DIR%_FULLCONTROL /T 
REM Reset to a known state inherited and nothing else
ICACLS %ROOTPATH%%DIR% /T /reset 
REM remove inheritance - but copy so we don't lose access 
ICACLS %ROOTPATH%%DIR% /inheritance:r

REM Give the rights to the Groups The last () is the rights being granted
ICACLS %ROOTPATH%%DIR% /GRANT:R %DOMAIN%FSP_%DIR%_MODIFY:(OI)(CI)(M)
ICACLS %ROOTPATH%%DIR% /GRANT:R %DOMAIN%FSP_%DIR%_READ:(OI)(CI)(R)
ICACLS %ROOTPATH%%DIR% /GRANT:R %DOMAIN%FSP_%DIR%_READexecute:(OI)(CI)(RX)
ICACLS %ROOTPATH%%DIR% /GRANT:R %DOMAIN%FSP_%DIR%_FULLCONTROL:(OI)(CI)(F)
ICACLS %ROOTPATH%%DIR% /GRANT:R %DOMAIN%FSP_%DIR%_WRITE:(OI)(CI)(W)

REM Remove rights from everyone else 
ICACLS %ROOTPATH%%DIR% /REMOVE:g "Authenticated Users"
ICACLS %ROOTPATH%%DIR% /REMOVE:g Everyone
ICACLS %ROOTPATH%%DIR% /REMOVE:g SYSTEM
ICACLS %ROOTPATH%%DIR% /REMOVE:g BUILTIN\Users
REM Show me what I've done 
ICACLS %ROOTPATH%%DIR% /T 
REM Now remove my self - If I am sure everything is ok
PAUSE
ICACLS %ROOTPATH%%DIR% /REMOVE:g BUILTIN\Administrators
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, members of the `FSP_%DIR%_MODIFY` group will be able to delete the `A` folder along with the other subfolders of `Two\`. I believe the OP doesn't want that (and currently has his permissions set to  disallow that).